# Can I set a password hint in Windows 8? If so, how?

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords

I'm trying to set a password hint for myself on Windows 8, but I don't seem to be able to find an option to do so. Googling "Windows 8 password hint" just provides tutorials on how to do so in Windows 7.

Is this option available? If so, how do I do it? If not, are there any alternatives or workarounds?

Comment: I think that you issue is because you're using a Windows Live account for your account not a Local User Account. (if your username is an Email address then you are using such account.) The online accounts do not have the Hint option at all. But if you'll change to a Local User account (do this in Setting>User Accounts) you will be able to set a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already created your Account/Password, I believe you will have to change your password in order for the text box to be available for filling in. Depending on Windows 8 or 8.1, you can do that by doing the following:

Windows 8 - Go to PC Settings -> Users -> Change Password

Windows 8.1 - PC Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in Options -> Change

This will prompt you to enter your current password, then create a new one along with a hint.

Once you have done so, you can restart the PC and you should see the hint become visible

Answer (score -1):

There should be an option do do so when you make/change your password. I also found [this](https://www.winhelp.us/user-management-in-windows.html) when researching.

Comment: Can you please place the relevant information in the answer itself?